IBM MQ Client - JMS Connection Pooling not working and connections are increasing After spring upgrade
After my springboot and the related IBM Jakarata libraries updates, i am seeing increasing in MQ Connections to the MQ Server during my PST and i believe MQ connection pooling is not working properly.
I couldnt identify the root cause of the error. I got the below error and after that point i am just seeing
2024-12-30 07:43:31.446 [org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#1-15] INFO  o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedTransactionRolledBackException: JMSCMQ0002: The method 'MQCMIT' failed.
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '1' ('MQCC_WARNING') reason '2003' ('MQRC_BACKED_OUT').

2024-12-30 07:43:31.855 [org.springframework.jms.JmsListenerEndpointContainer#0-49] INFO  o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0020: This session is closed.


Do you see any errors in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG when you get the 2003?

Treat this a comment. with some code to share. Try monitoring the number of connections when the concurrency has been throttled the connections eg.

    @JmsListener(destination = "${app.queue.name}", concurrency = "2-3")

which sets the connections to a minimum and maximum value.
